# Parsing a formula with rlang

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to learn how to write a domain specific language in R with `rlang`. This is just a mini example to understand how parsing and operations work.

Say I have the following data:

```
> top <- seq(2,10,2)
> bottom <- rep(2,length(top))
> times <- rep(10,length(top))
> df <- tibble::tibble(top,bottom,times)
> df
    top bottom times
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2.00   2.00  10.0
2  4.00   2.00  10.0
3  6.00   2.00  10.0
4  8.00   2.00  10.0
5  10.0   2.00  10.0
```

I would like a domain specific language that takes the following examples

1.

```
df_result1 <- divi(top | bottom ~ times, df)
```

2.

```
df_result2 <- divi(top | bottom ~ 1, df)
```

And produces the following:

1.

```
> df_result1
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    top bottom times result
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2.00   2.00  10.0   10.0
2  4.00   2.00  10.0   20.0
3  6.00   2.00  10.0   30.0
4  8.00   2.00  10.0   40.0
5  10.0   2.00  10.0   50.0
```

2.

```
> df_result2
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  result
   <dbl>
1   3.00
```

In `dplyr` lingo the functions are:

1.

```
df_result1 <- df %>% mutate(result = (top/bottom)*times)
```

2.

```
df_result2 <- df %>% summarise(result = mean((top/bottom)))
```

### Update

After some ad hoc work I came up with the following for one of the cases. It is probably technically ugly, but it gets the job done.

```
divi <- function(form, data){
  data %>% mutate(result=eval_tidy(f_lhs(f_lhs(form)))/
                      eval_tidy(f_rhs(f_lhs(form)))*
  eval_tidy(f_rhs(form)))
}

divi(top | bottom ~ times, df)

    top bottom times ressult
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     2      2    10      10
2     4      2    10      20
3     6      2    10      30
4     8      2    10      40
5    10      2    10      50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have assumed that the general case here is that we want to replace | with / and then evaluate the left hand side taking its mean if the right hand side is 1 and multiplying by the right hand side and appending all that to data if not.

This does not use rlang but seems pretty short.  It breaks the formula up into left hand side, right hand side and environment (`lhs`, `rhs`, `e`) and evaluates the left hand side while replacing | with / giving `eval_lhs`.  Then it checks whether the right hand side is 1 and if so it returns the mean of `eval_lhs`; otherwise, it appends `eval_lhs` times the evaluated right hand side to `data` and returns that.

```
library(tibble)

divi <- function(formula, data) {
   lhs <- formula[[2]]
   rhs <- formula[[3]]
   e <- environment(formula)
   eval_lhs <- eval(do.call("substitute", list(lhs, list("|" = `/`))), data, e)
   if (identical(rhs, 1)) tibble(result = mean(eval_lhs))
   else as.tibble(cbind(data, result = eval_lhs * eval(rhs, data, e)))
}
```

Now some test runs:

```
divi(top | bottom ~ times, df)
## # A tibble: 5 x 4
##     top bottom times result
##   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1  2.00   2.00  10.0   10.0
## 2  4.00   2.00  10.0   20.0
## 3  6.00   2.00  10.0   30.0
## 4  8.00   2.00  10.0   40.0
## 5 10.0    2.00  10.0   50.0

divi(top | bottom ~ 1, df)
## # A tibble: 1 x 1
##   result
##    <dbl>
## 1   3.00

divi((top - bottom) | (top + bottom) ~ times^2, df)
## # A tibble: 5 x 4
##     top bottom times result
##   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1  2.00   2.00  10.0    0  
## 2  4.00   2.00  10.0   33.3
## 3  6.00   2.00  10.0   50.0
## 4  8.00   2.00  10.0   60.0
## 5 10.0    2.00  10.0   66.7
```

If we are willing to restrict the input so that the only forms of input allowed are:

```
variable | variable ~ variable
variable | variable ~ 1
```

and all variables are columns in the data and no variable can appear more than once in the formula then we could simplify it like this:

```
divi0 <- function(formula, data) {
  d <- get_all_vars(formula, data)
  if (ncol(d) == 2) tibble(result = mean(d[[1]] / d[[2]]))
  else as.tibble(cbind(data, result = d[[1]] / d[[2]] * d[[3]]))
}

divi0(top | bottom ~ times, df)
divi0(top | bottom | top ~ 1, df)
```

This simplification only uses the number of and order of variables in the formula ignoring the operators so that, for example, these each give the same answer since they all list the same variables in the same order:

```
divi0(top | bottom ~ times, df)
divi0(~ top + bottom | times, df)
divi0(~ top * bottom * times, df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have been a regular R user for a couple years, but it seems that there is another side to R I have never used. `eval` is one of many commands that I have not touched. What is the purpose of `eval`? Why not just execute the command as one normally would?

Comment: The fact that a formula might represent R code is just a convention. R does not know that.  We have to evaluate the formula to actually run it.  If you are willing to make additional assumptions such as the formula can only be of the form `variable | variable ~ variable` or `variable | variable ~ 1` (so, for example, the last example in the answer would not be allowed) then we could could avoid `eval`.  `eval` is generally frowned upon but if you want to be able to run arbitrary code there is no alternative.

Comment: Have added a simplification that does not use `eval` that could be used if we are willing to specify that only the indicated formulas are allowed.